# JavaScript: Why is there different object Syntax?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am confused about the two different types of objects in JavaScript and when you are supposed to use one over the other?

**Object Example 1:**

```
 var Player = {
      firstName : 'Foo',
      lastName : 'Bar',
      getFullName : function(){
           return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      }
 }
```

**Object Example 2:**

```
 var Player = function(newFirstName, newLastName){
      this.firstName = newFirstName;
      this.lastName = newLastName;
      this.getFullName = function(){
           return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      }
 }
```

Is it just when you need an object to have a constructor, you would use the example 2?